# Getting a value from http request

Tags: go

I'm trying to get a value for example "id" from this site:

`http://api.roblox.com/groups/7585110`

this is my code:

```golang
url := fmt.Sprintf("https://groups.roblox.com/v1//groups/7585110") 
resp, err := http.Get(url)
```

and then I do:

```golang
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
```

and then:

```golang
sb := string(body)
```

so if I want to print the stuff from the website:

```
fmt.Println(sb)
```

and I get the following output:

```json
{
    "Name": "Catalysm",
    "Id": 7585110,
    "Owner": {
        "Name": "Scypno",
        "Id": 1590107797
    },
    "EmblemUrl": "http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=5627136670",
    "Description": "",
    "Roles": [{
        "Name": "Member",
        "Rank": 1
    }, {
        "Name": "Admin",
        "Rank": 254
    }, {
        "Name": "Owner",
        "Rank": 255
    }]
}
```

but I want to make a variable named "id" to get the following output:

```golang
7585110
```

is that possible? and if so, how?

Comment: I hope i was clear this time, or this will be my third time getting my question closed.

Comment: You can use `encoding/json` to decode the response body into a struct, have that struct have an `Id` field, then print that field.

Comment: Thank you, but since i am a beginner i don't really understand what you are saying @mkopriva can you give me a simple example maybe?

Comment: You can see an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58434023/how-to-parse-http-response-body-to-json-format-in-golang

Comment: I see, thanks alot!

Comment: One more question, how do i print the "id" value from what i copied from that post? @mkopriva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a struct that matches the json structure and decode the repsonse into an instance of that struct. You can omit those fields that you don't need.

Say if the given json looks like the following

```json
{
  "id": 7585110,
  "name": "Catalysm",
  "description": "",
  "owner": {
    "buildersClubMembershipType": "None",
    "userId": 1590107797,
    "username": "Scypno",
    "displayName": "Scypno"
  },
  "shout": {
    "body": "Ill be happy if you check out the clothing mall i made :)",
    "poster": {
      "buildersClubMembershipType": "None",
      "userId": 1590107797,
      "username": "Scypno",
      "displayName": "Scypno"
    },
    "created": "2020-08-28T19:14:46.113Z",
    "updated": "2021-02-06T18:43:38.223Z"
  },
  "memberCount": 28,
  "isBuildersClubOnly": false,
  "publicEntryAllowed": true
}
```

and, for example, you only need the `id` and the `name` field, then you can declare a struct that looks like this

```golang
type Object struct {
    Id   int    `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```

and use it like this

```golang
resp, err := http.Get("https://groups.roblox.com/v1/groups/7585110")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

var obj Object
if err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&obj); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(obj.Id, obj.Name)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you alot for taking the time to make that. That will save me like 5 years of figuring things out.

Answer (score 1):

You can either create a new struct to hold the JSON data or you can just create a map of type `map[string]interface{}` to do that.

> Code is present [here](https://play.golang.org/p/zKAtd8g7cmY).

For `map[string]interface{}`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    jsonData := `{"Name":"Catalysm","Id":7585110,"Owner":{"Name":"Scypno","Id":1590107797},"EmblemUrl":"http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=5627136670","Description":"","Roles":[{"Name":"Member","Rank":1},{"Name":"Admin","Rank":254},{"Name":"Owner","Rank":255}]}`


   mySimpleMap := make(map[string]interface{})
   err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonData), &mySimpleMap) 
   if err != nil {
       // panic(err)
       fmt.Println("error while unmarshal", err)
   } else {
       fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(mySimpleMap["Id"]))
       fmt.Printf("%f\n", mySimpleMap["Id"])
       fmt.Println(int(mySimpleMap["Id"].(float64)))
   }
}
```

Output:

```sh
float64
7585110.000000
7585110
```

As the value type is `interface{}` so go has inferred the ID field's type as `float64`. You'll have to convert it to `int` if that is required.

Otherwise, you can create a struct for this JSON document, like,

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Asset struct{
    Id int
}

func main() {
    jsonData := `{"Name":"Catalysm","Id":7585110,"Owner":{"Name":"Scypno","Id":1590107797},"EmblemUrl":"http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=5627136670","Description":"","Roles":[{"Name":"Member","Rank":1},{"Name":"Admin","Rank":254},{"Name":"Owner","Rank":255}]}`

 
   myAsset := Asset{} 
   err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonData), &myAsset) 
   if err != nil {
       // panic(err)
       fmt.Println("error while unmarshal", err)
   } else {
       fmt.Printf("%d", myAsset.Id) 
   }   
}
```

This way you won't have to do typecasting but you'll have to create a `struct`.